# Kernel32 API call from registry

Tags: winapi

I've recently noticed an entry in the registry on my system: HKLM\Software\Classes\FirefoxHTML\DefaultIcon, with value kernel32::GetLongPathNameW(w R8, w .R7, i 1024)i .R6,1

I've not been able to find anything in MSDN about this way of registering an app handler; is there a document about this method?

Comment: Looks like a bug in Firefox. They probably meant to call the function and put the result in the registry key. (You'll notice that the icon doesn't actually appear correctly in Explorer, so whatever it is, it's not working.)

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682212(v=vs.85).aspx) it's supposed to be the "full path to the executable name of the object application and the resource index of the icon within the executable". For example "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\Blend.exe,-32515"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That string is [System plug-in syntax](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/System/System.html#func) used by [NSIS installers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System).

This must be [a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1186923) in the Firefox installer (or other Firefox related tools), the Windows shell has never supported syntax like this.

The [Windows shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127427(v=vs.85).aspx) accepts a path and a optional icon index, nothing more:

> Any file that contains an icon is acceptable, including .ico, .exe, and .dll files. If there is more than one icon in the file, the path should be followed by a comma, and then the index of the icon.